# How to define actionmailer subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Is there a way to define ActionMailer subjects in the email view erb?

Something like:

```
<%= set_subject("abc") %>
```

I would like to use class variable values in the subject through string interpolation and was wondering if there was a way to have all the email parameters in one place so I can edit them cleanly.

Comment: Why would you want to set the subject in the view? The subject is usually unique for all the view formats

Comment: Its a great way to have all the data for a message in one place without using settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line at the beginning of the view.

```
<% message.subject = "abc" %>
```